# Best way to store a password in C#, so that the user cannot access it?

Tags: c#, encryption

I am making an offline password manager using winforms, with a master password that the user has to enter before the user can access all his/her passwords. Now, I want to store the master password, to compare with the master password the user has just entered, and if they are the same, decrypt the files storing all the user's passwords, and display all the user's passwords.

Where can I store the user's password on the user's machine? I cannot just put it into AppData, the registry or a similar folder, since I do not want the user to see the password, since someone else could be using the machine when the user left it on. That is the whole idea of having a master password. I can of course encrypt the file where I store the password, but then where would I store the encryption key? I don't think hard coding the encryption key would be a good idea, since the key would be the same for any person who installs my program, which I don't think would be ideal.

I cannot use an external database, this is an offline password manager. Any ideas or ways to improve the question would be appreciated. I don't need anything crazy secure, just a place where the user, other users on the machine, or a program would not be able to access the master password. I am using c# .net and winforms and I am using the DESCryptoServiceProvider class and a CryptoStream to encrypt and decrypt the actual passwords stored in the password manager.

I am new to C# and StackOverflow, I realize this question is a little vague and not phrased nicely, and probably might get taken down (just like most of my questions), so any help on how to improve it would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey hey, what about MD5 encryption? You could store the hashed password in a textfile. If an user access the password there is no problem because the encryption is just one way so you eighter need a encryptation key

Comment: @AdrianEfford Can't tell if you're being serious or not! MD5 is not encryption and is certainly not appropriate for hashing passwords.

Comment: @phuzi & why should MD5 not be appropriate for this purpose?

Comment: @AdrianEfford If you're going to do it properly you might as well use an appropriate algorithm! I appreciate that it's offline, but what if it becomes something more in the future!

Comment: From Wikipedia's MD5 article "As of 2019, MD5 continues to be widely used, in spite of its well-documented weaknesses and deprecation by security experts."

Comment: @phuzi using MD5 and a "salt" there should be no problem in my opinion

Comment: @AdrianEfford please, read some articles. Considering md5 as a "secure" hashing algorithm is nowadays one of the most dangerous thoughts, there are rainbow tables easyly found all over the web. even a salt, which MUST be saved together with the hash makes the salt useless because an attacker WILL have access to it.

Comment: @TinoZ I will read about it. Tank you for the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply don't save it. Encrypt the other passwords with the master password and then throw the master password away. Ask for it again when you need to decrypt.

If you don't save it, it can't be compromised.

Comment: Many modern software have option to "Remember password".

Comment: A lot of modern software prioritizes convenience over security. When you make software, you need to find the right balance for your users and the information they store in your system.

Comment: Are you saying what all of them are insecure?

Comment: Security isn't binary. Systems can be more or less secure. And I'll definitely argue that storing something is less secure than not storing it at all.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the password itself as the encryption key. But first you should pass the password thru a [key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function). See [KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.core.keyderivationalgorithmprovider?view=winrt-19041) for corresponding c# implementation.

You might also need some mechanism to determine if the password is correct, like encrypting a known value that can be checked if it decrypts correctly or not.

Comment: In fact, use the password as encryption key is the best way, but in that case there is an inconvenient : Even the administrator could never find back the password.

Comment: @Siegfried.V: Making the password recoverable inherently makes the password _discoverable_ (i.e. by attackers). It undermines the entire security protocol. It's the digital equivalent of putting a post it note on your desk.

Answer (score 1):

Well, dispite that there are several offline password managers around, you should simply use an encryption algorith of your choice, serialize the user passwords with the typed in private key and, just encrypt it. While decrypting, just test the decrypted object, if it was successful. If not, the password was incorrect.

While md5 was mentioned. The biggest disadvantage of storing a hashed password are rainbow tables. Well it wasn't asked for security purposes, but with a simple encryption everything is done, without taking any "master password storage for password storage"